# How to add column in the javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
    function answer(){
            var u='';
            var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
            var total = num1 * num1;
            for(var x=1; x<=num1;x++){
                u=u+x;
                for(var y = u ; y<=num1; y++){
                }
            }
            console.log(u);
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num1" name="">
    <button type="submit" onclick="answer()">Answer</button>
```

Help how to add a column using for loop  Sorry guys I disturbed you

My example problem if the user input 3 the output becomes

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform most of your operations in the nested `for` loop.

```js
function answer() {
    var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
    for (var x = 1; x <= num1; x++) {
        var u = '';
        for (var y = 1; y <= num1; y++) {
            u = u + ((x-1) * num1 + y) + ' ';
        }
        console.log(u);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num1" name="">
<button type="submit" onclick="answer()">Answer</button>
```

Comment: Thank you sir . Sir is it possible to add the sum of rows for example  1 + 2 + 3 =6?

Comment: @woofMaranon Certainly: https://jsfiddle.net/uvqadz37/